# JAVA creating instance of nested static class with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, nested-class, static-classes

I want to create an instance of **nested** **static** class with reflection.
I have the following code:

```
if (Modifier.isStatic(nestedClass.getModifiers())) {
                //TODO - WRITE HERE SOMETHING
 } else {
    ctor = nestedClass.getDeclaredConstructor(outerClass);
    ctor.setAccessible(true);
    testInstance = ctor.newInstance(outerInstance);
 }
```

but cant figure out what to do within the if statement.
Some help or advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Just call the constructor - `Class.newInstance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested static class doesn't require outer instance, so try doing the same as in `else` but remove `outerClass` and `outerInstance` from constructor's arguments.

```
ctor = nestedClass.getDeclaredConstructor();//no outer class in argument
ctor.setAccessible(true);
testInstance = ctor.newInstance();//no outer instance in argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Class<MyClass> nestedClass = MyClass.class;
if (Modifier.isStatic(nestedClass.getModifiers())) {
     MyClass instance = nestedClass.newInstance();
     System.out.println(instance);
}
Output:
MainClass$MyClass@1db9742
```

Comment: Thx. But, if the nestedClass is also private i get an exception.
any way around it?